# Use ng serve for multiple machines simultaneously Angular 2

Tags: angular

I need to run my angular application in multiple machines at a time. I can provide access to other machine using `ng serve --public-host 192.168.1.1` but I need to run the same app on my machine as well.

Is there any way to run same appllicaion on multiple machines simultaneously?

I have tried with `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0` but when using my IP in my colleague's machine It is displaying error :

[image: Check this]

Need Help.

Comment: Just run it on your machine and make the other machines access it? https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6349

Comment: somehow I am not able to run it on localhost and an other address at same time

Comment: You can access your own ip adress from your machine

Comment: @warrior you just have to run it on one machine and access it by the other...

Comment: @Carsten How to provide access to other machines ?

Comment: @warrior is the machine on the same network?

Comment: @Carsten yes the machines are on same n/w

Comment: @warrior Then run it on one machine like in the link i provided and access the running app by the ip of that machine....

Comment: @Carsten No it's not working on my colleague's machine with my IP and port

Comment: It's showing this site can not be reched... 192.168.1.2 took too much to respond

Comment: @warrior which flags are you using with ng serve

Comment: I am using `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check` to provide access

Answer (score 1):

Try that otherwise

```
ng serve --host 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: I am using --host 192.168.1.1 to provide access to particular IP but at that time if I run my localhost then it's not working

Comment: The answer above if your app to be accessible using both localhost:4200  and 192.168.1.1:4200

Comment: yes I have tried it but it's working on my system but not in other system ?

Comment: I used my IP and Port to run it on other system ... is it ok ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164953/discussion-between-david-and-warrior).

Answer (score 1):

I know Iam very late to this question. But I have the solution for this.

step 1: Disable the **antivirus/ firewall** in your computer (which has the code running).

step 2: Connect all the devices to the **same network** (wifi). (The computer in which the code is running and the other device where you want to cast your localhost).

step 3: Run this command in the terminal. `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check`

step 4: Check the ip address by running the command `ipconfig` in the terminal.

step 5: Copy the **ipV4** address. eg: 192.168.0.10

step 6: Open the browser in the other device and type http://192.168.0.10:4200. Likewise you can use this link in multiple devices.

Here the 4200 is the port where my project is running. If it is different in your case, use that port number instead.

Comment: I have faced the same issue. According to your solution, I disabled the Antivirus/firewall in my system and it worked for me.